# How to include an empty folder in a zip file

Tags: ant

I have created a zip file with many folders and files in it.

```
    <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
    <mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/core/dist"/>
     <zip destfile="${buildDirectory}/core/dist/core.zip">
        <zipfileset dir="${buildDirectory}/core/" prefix="core/bin">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </zipfileset>
        <zipfileset dir="${buildDirectory}/core/src/resources" prefix="core/conf">
            <include name="log4j.properties" />
            <include name="core.properties" />
            <include name="conf.xml" />
        </zipfileset>
        <zipfileset dir="${buildDirectory}/algorithm/testData" prefix="core/data">
            <include name="defs.properties" />
            <include name="proto.aza" />                
        </zipfileset>
```

So the zip now has

/bin

/conf

/data

I also need to include (add) an empty /logs folder in the zip structure.
How do I do that.

thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'get filled after extraction' ?. If its simple jar/zip packed file then doing 'jar -uvf existing.jar path/to/empty/folder' works if you not concerned during time of packing

Answer (score 0):

The least clumsy way I can find of doing this is to create an empty directory somewhere first, and then include it in your zipfile.  Cutting down your example a bit, to get a zip with just an empty logs directory in it, you could write:

```
<mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/core/dist"/>
<mkdir dir="${buildDirectory}/core/dist/logs"/>
<zip destfile="${buildDirectory}/core/dist/core.zip">
    <zipfileset dir="${buildDirectory}/core/dist/logs" fullpath="logs"/>
</zip>
```